# how to perform row by row operation in pandas

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns,  `last_name` and `description`

What is an elegant way to see if `description` contains the `last_name` on each row?

I have a ugly

---

```
for i in range(0,len(df0)):
    df0['last_name_position'].loc[i] = \ 
        df0['description'].loc[i].find(df0['last_name'].loc[i])
```

---

running.

This is basically the same task as 
https://exceljet.net/formula/cell-contains-specific-text

Answer (score 4):

The same result can be achieved with [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df0['last_name_position'] = \ 
    df0.apply(lambda x: x.description.find(x.last_name), axis=1)
```

In case you don't need to find an index of substring:

```
df0['last_name_position'] = \ 
    df0.apply(lambda x: x.last_name in x.description, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!

Answer (score 0):

What might be nicer is to loop over the rows using the index. Then do your comparison using the `in` keyword:

```
import pandas as pd 

a = pd.DataFrame([['Smith','Some description'],['Jones','Some Jones description']], columns=['last_name','description'])

for rname in a.index:
    row = a.loc[rname]

    it_contains = row['last_name'] in row['description']
    print "Description contains last name:", it_contains

# Outputs:
# Description contains last name: False
# Description contains last name: True
```

Comment: I'd say this is anti-Pandas. For simple comparisons, there's no need to iterate over a Pandas index. There are methods, `pd.DataFrame.apply` and `pd.Series.apply`, which make this redundant.

Comment: How would you do it instead? I guess using pandas DataFrame.apply() function? I picked it up about a month ago, so I welcome more Panda-nic suggestions

Comment: Exactly. Or, just in this specific case, list comprehensions are also more Pandorable.

Comment: @jpp offered a really elegant solution   df0['last_name_in_description'] = [i in j for i, j in zip(df0['last_name'], df0['description'])]  Thank you. (your username happens to coincide with the initials of my best friend's.)

Comment: @Marshall, No problem, I deleted my answer since it's also present in the marked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

a = pd.DataFrame([['Smith','Some description'],['Jones','Some Jones description']], columns=['last_name','description'])
a['Match']=a.apply(lambda x: x['last_name'] in x['description'], axis=1)
a.head()

last_name   description             Match
0   Smith   Some description        False
1   Jones   Some Jones description  True
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy reply!